# SQL code not going through in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I entered the following SQL code into phpmyadmin:

> i1: display inventory rows for apple
>   list the quantity total for apple

```
select fruitID, sum( quantity ) from inventory
where fruitID=
(select fruitID from fruit where name = “apple”);
```

I am getting the error message:

> unknown column "apple"

and it is not going through. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: you are missing group by. pls show us the columns of fruit and inventory as well

Comment: Proper formatting for errors and code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `“` and `”`. You should use the usual quotation marks `"` which are used to identify string literals correctly.

Try it again with the usual quotation marks:

```
SELECT fruitID, sum( quantity ) 
FROM inventory 
WHERE fruitID= 
    (SELECT fruitID 
    FROM fruit 
    WHERE name = "apple");
```

Comment: It says I can't publicly upvote because my account is too new but I will mark it as an answer